# How to detect when a tab is restored after it has been closed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having issues with JS state after the state has been changed but reverts back to the state it was loaded in when the user closes the tab and restores it using cmd/ctrl + shift + t.

Normally when the pages are loaded using Vue's `mounted()` lifecycle hook, data is fetched from the server through the API using ajax. However, when the tab is restored, it loads the data as it was when it was first loaded the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, Ctrl-Shift-T acts just like Ctrl-Tab, it switches the tab but it does not reinitialize its contents.

You can mimick your needed behaviour by the following sequence:

1) Server-side assign every request a random, unique ID available in JS

2) On `unload` (or `beforeunload`, experiment here), add the ID to an array cookie of unloaded IDs

3) On `load`, check if the ID is in the array cookie. If it is, then the tabbed was unloaded before load. `load` seems to trigger on Ctrl-Shift-T

4) Don't forget to purge the cookie id array every now and then (maybe also store add time).

You may experiment with using `window.sessionStorage` instead of cookies/local storage, I don't trust it enough as I haven't used it. The principle is the same, to mark down somewhere when the window is unloaded, then check in onload.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out. Would `localStorage` work for this?

Comment: I'm sure `localStorage` will work. I'm not sure of the `sessionStorage` lifecycle, if it is restored on Ctrl-Shift-T, you could try it out.
Also, I notice `onload` is also triggered on Ctrl-Shift-T, so you may use that instead of `onfocus`... I haven't tested these cross-browser recently, I just remember from an older implementation, so ymmv, make sure to cross-test.

Comment: I found the code and updated the workflow in the answer. It seems it needs server-size generated ids, so this can be easily broken if you are using cacheable pages. If this is the case, check the other answer for solutions that don't require unique request ids.

Answer (score 0):

Might also work for you:

1) On `load`, use `window.history` to add a slug to the url, such as `#dorefresh`. Then, on the subsequent `load`, check if the slug exists and trigger refresh.

OR

2) Add a timestamp on page generation (make it UTC to be sure you don't run into timezone issues). Then on `load` check if the page load time is too much into the future of generation time. This is vulnerable to time errors, also don't use if your page is cacheable.

OR

3) For stale AJAX requests: maybe adding a `no-store` header (to the AJAX response only, not the main page) might prevent the browser storing a cached copy.